Reverse Proxy with forward-target
I have configured a reverse proxy in Apache2.
It gets requests by HTTPS - unwraps the HTTPS and then forwards to local HTTP-processes for /web and /rest.
<VirtualHost *:4443>
    ProxyPass /web http://127.0.0.1:8080/web
    ProxyPassReverse /web http://127.0.0.1:8080/web

    ProxyPass /rest http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse /rest http://127.0.0.1:8181

    ServerName myserver123.abc.xyz.org
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/server.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/server.key

This is working fine. Every request to / is forbidden.
But now I try to forward every request to / to /web instead of the 403-forbidden response.
I inserted this before the ServerName line.
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/web
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/web

But does not work.
All I get in the browser is

Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled
server port. Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

How can I get me forward from / to /web?
